# Redirect action to mobile view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mobile-website

```
public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

This is what I have for my current site within the HomeController. How can I detect if the action is called from a mobile device, and if it is, re-direct to MobileHome.aspx instead of Home.aspx.

I don't need to know the details of the device, because I am implementing the view in JQuery Mobile, which should adjust itself correctly depending on the view it's rendered in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an override on the Controller class. I have not tested this, so consider it pseudo code:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (this.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;

        viewResult.ViewName = "Mobile" + viewResult.ViewName;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

You can use the Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to determine if the device is mobile (obviously), and then check to see if the result it a view. However, changing the view name is not sufficient if you pass an actual view to the result of your action.